# Newly Created folder not showing up Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg

I have created a new folder (myFolder) in my **Child Theme** and added some files (fileA.php, fileB.php) in it, Nothing is showing up when I go to

***Appearance >> Theme Editor >> Child Theme.***

**Note:** The folder (myFolder) and the files (fileA.php, fileB.php) are not there in the **Parent Theme**. Created the folder and files using FTP.

It's not possible?? Or I'm doing something wrong.

**Please guide me.**

Comment: Are you sure you connected to the right ftp? there should be no problem with theme editor showing the uploaded `.php` files. Could you include a image of your folder/file structure, maybe you placed the files in the wrong location.

Comment: I also added the WP File Manager plugin, the folder and files are showing in it but not showing in Appearance >> Theme Editor >> Child Theme.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast [link](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/14536346?key=850fa94229fb2801a61be244b7ef610f)